# java loop logic issue

Tags: java, loops

This feed method is supposed to first increase the energy state and decrease hungry state, use a dumplings meal (which can be purchased in the shop) then see that the item purchased from the shop, is a positive number or greater than `0`. Then ensure that hungry and energy states do not go out of bounds (if it does print warning statements).

If it reaches the border of `100` then start increment overfeed, every time method is executed, if overfeed is greater than `4` then execute `die method()`.

If it meets criteria running feed method will print `Eating...` and `I have ate enough(...)` statements.

```
@Override
protected void feed() {

       decHungry(10);
       incEnergy(10);
       shop.useDumplingsMEAL();

       do {

           if (shop.dumplingsMEAL <= 0) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot eat right now, You need to purchase item in the shop");
       }

           else if  (hungry <= 0 && energy >= 100) {

            System.out.print("\nI have ate enough! My hungry state is " + hungry +
                    " and my energy state is " + energy + "." );
            overfeed++;

            while (overfeed>4)

            {
                die();
                System.out.println("You have overfed me.");
            }
        }

           else {
         System.out.println("\nEating..."); 

        System.out.println("I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is " + energy 
                +" and hungry state is " + hungry + "."); 
        overfeed = 0;
        }   
}
```

Comment: What is your code doing now what it shouldn't and what would you like it to do?

Comment: I explained above what I would like it to do, now there is a following error: insert while expression to complete a do statement.

Comment: also, indentate your code properly so that it is easier to read

Comment: Where is the rest of code? `do .. while`

Comment: okay. a do-while statement should look like following:
do{ xxxx }while(condition), your does not look like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a method called `feed`. This method looks like it should feed once if it can when it's called. Get rid of all the loops. If you want to keep it, read on [do..while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop.

```
if(no food){

    // nothing to feed

} else if (hunger level 0 or below & energy 100 or more){ // by the way hunger level should never go below 0 and energy should never go over 100

    // increment overfeed

    if(overfeed more than 4) {

        // die
    }  

} else {

   // feed

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error message says, the syntax for do while is:

```
do {
    // Do stuff
} while(some condition);
```

Also you seem to have some conditions that won't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are either having problem with your braces {} and indentation or don't understand properly how to use do-while loop.

Do-while should look like following:

```
do{
    //making stuff
}
while(condition of loop);
```

At the moment your code looks like following:

```
do{
    if(){
    }
    else{
        while{
        }
    }
}
```